# Conditions including comparison of consequtive elements within columns

Tags: r

Could you please help me with the following task. Here is a template of my dataset:

```
Category <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
PrevRule <- c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
UserRule <- c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Correct <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(Category, PrevRule, UserRule, Correct)
```

I need to create an additional `PP` column according to the following rules:

- `i` is row index. `n` is maximum rows for each `Category`.
- For `Category == 1`:
  If `Correct[i:i+2] == 0` then `PP[i+2:n] = UserRule[i+2]` 
  Else `PP = NA`
- For `Category > 1`:
  Do `PP = PrevRule` until `Correct[i:i+2] == 0`
  Then `PP[i+2:n] = UserRule[i+2]`

So, in the end the `PP` column should look like in the following table (column starting with NA)

```
   Category PrevRule UserRule Correct PP
1         1       -1        2       0 NA
2         1       -1        2       0 NA
3         1       -1        2       0  2
4         1       -1        1       1  2
5         1       -1        1       1  2
6         1       -1        1       1  2
7         1       -1        1       1  2
8         1       -1        1       1  2
9         2        1        1       0  1
10        2        1        1       0  1
11        2        1        2       1  1
12        2        1        0       0  1
13        2        1        0       0  1
14        2        1        0       0  0
15        2        1        2       1  0
16        2        1        2       1  0
17        2        1        2       1  0
18        2        1        2       1  0
19        2        1        2       1  0
20        3        2        2       0  2
21        3        2        0       0  2
22        3        2        0       0  2
23        3        2        0       0  0
24        3        2        1       1  0
25        3        2        1       1  0
26        3        2        1       1  0
27        3        2        1       1  0
```

Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Please be more clear about what do you want to do. For example what do you mean by "(Correct x = Correct x+1 = Correct x+2 = 0)". What is x?

Comment: Thank you @Qaswed for your comment, I have added more information. x is a random position of an element in a column, so x, x+1 and x+2 are consecutive elements in the same column that should be equal to zero.

Comment: So x is an index to Label the x-th row? Imo labeling rows by `i` and columns by `j` is way more common and thus more intuitive.

Comment: @Qaswed, Yes, it is the x-th row indicator. Thank you for the information, I will change it in my post.

Comment: So, why not writing "First, if "Correct i" is i-th element in `Correct`, then "Correct i+1", and "Correct i+2" would be the i+1th and i+2th elements respectively."? This can be shortend in `R` language to  `Correct[i]`, `Correct[i+1]` or `Correct[i+2]` and doesn't need further Explanation.

Comment: It would also help if you would distinguish between *giving a value* (like `PP[i] <- PrevRule[i]`) and *checking for equivalence* (like `Correct[i] == 0`).

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Your example doesn't fit to your rule "`PP = PrevRule` until `Correct[i:i+2] == 0`". In case of `i=20` you would see that all `Correct[20:22]`are `0`. Then you would say that `PP[22:27]` should be `UserRule[22]` (which is `0`), but in your example `PP[22]` equals `2` (and not `0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was realy difficult to understand what you ment, but here is my solution. It is not perfect as it uses a `while`-Loop but it should work:

```
ret <- array(dim = nrow(df))
i <- 1
while(i < nrow(df) - 3){
  if(Category[i] == 1 & all(Correct[i + 0:2] == 0)){
    tmp <- max(which(Category==1)) #end of category 1
    ret[(i + 2):tmp] <- UserRule[i+2]
    #set index i to the index-value of the last element in category 1
    i <- tmp
  }else{
    ret[i] <- NA #actual not necessary, because PP is NA per default.
  }
  print("From now on, I will only ask clear questions!")
  if(Category[i] >= 2){
    ret[i] <- PrevRule[i]

    if(all(Correct[(i-2):i] == 0)){#3 consecutive 0 in Correct
      tmp <-  max(which(Category == Category[i])) #end of current category
      ret[i:tmp] <- UserRule[i]
      i <- tmp #set index i to the index-value of the last element in the current category
    } 
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

df$PP <- ret
```

Comment: Qaswed, thank you very much for the perfectly working code and great sense of humour =) Since I was reminded multiple times that I should ask only clear questions, could you please explain or give me a link that would help me to understand better why you wrote `i <- 1`, `i <- tmp`, and `i <- i + 1`. Many thanks again!

Comment: `i <- 1` is used to initialise `i` (it has to be in the workspace when `while(i < ...)` checks the value of `i`). As the comments in the code say (now, after a recent edit) `i <- tmp` is used to set `i` to the index-value of the last element in the current category. And `i <- i + 1` increases `i` by 1 (otherwise the `while`-loop would never end). These commands are all needed because I use `while`. There are surely smarter solutions without `while`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will read more about the `while` function in order to understand it better.

Comment: `while` will check whether the condition (here `i < nrow(df) - 3`) is true or not. If it is, it does everything that come in the bracket `{...}`. Then it checks again the condition and so on. `while`-loops can be tricky because it can happen that they run for ever.

Comment: One more question: when I apply the function to different data, I constantly get 4 `NA`s in the end of  `PP` column. For example, if we take this data:
`Category <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
PrevRule <- c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
UserRule <- c(2, 0, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2) 
Correct <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) 
df <- data.frame(Category, PrevRule, UserRule, Correct)`
and run your script, we will get four `NA` in the column `PP`.

Comment: Actually your rule for `Category > 1` are not complete. In your first example consider `i=12`. In this case `all(Correct[12:14] == 0)` is true, so your rule is `PP[14:19] <- UserRule[14]`. But it is not clear what should happen do `PP[12]` is it still `PrevRule[12]`? And what is about `PP[13]`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `PP[12]` and `PP[13]` should have the corresponding `PrevRule` values. Immediately when `Category` changes from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3 and so on, `PP`should get a value of `PrevRule` without any respect to other conditions, but once a set of three `0` occurs in `Correct`, lets call it `i`, `i+1` and `i+2`, the `PP[i+2]` should get the value of the element `UserRule[i+2]`, whereas `PP[i]` and `PP[i+1]` get the corresponding `PrevRule` values. How does it explain the presence of 4 NAs in the end of `PP`?

Comment: I have changed `while(i < nrow(df) - 3)` to `while(i <= nrow(df))` and 4 `NA` disappeared. Could you please explain me your rationale for writing `nrow(df) - 3`? Thank you in advance!